# Retrieving correct record from multidimentional array

Tags: php

I'm having a mental freeze moment. If I have an array in the following format:

```
$myData = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [busID] => 5
            [type] => SMS
            [number] => 5128888888
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [busID] => 5
            [type] => APP
            [number] => 5125555555
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [busID] => 5
            [type] => APP
            [number] => 5129999988
            [verified] => 1
            [default] => 0
        )

)
```

And I only have an var for ID of the record, how do I retrieve the rest of the detail for that set.

```
$myID = 2;
// get number 5125555555 and it's type

echo $myData[][$myID]['number']; // ???
```

Comment: `foreach` loop? And those are objects in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your data arranged your going to have to loop through your array to identify the object corresponding to $myID.

`foreach($myData as $object) if($object->id == $myID) echo $object->number;`

The alternative is to arrange your $myData as an associative array with the id field as the key. Then you could access it simply with `$myData[$myID]->number`.

Comment: Overlooked that it was an array of objects, edited to correct.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to avoid using a loop because there are multiple places in the code where I need to reference different numbers and their details. Perhaps I could rewrite the array to make those more accessible, perhaps putting the id in the first node of the array? If something like that is even possible: $myData[$myID]['number']

Comment: If by putting the id in the first node of the array you mean setting the id as the key for the array, then its definitely possible, as long as the id's are unique.`$newData = array(); foreach($myData as $object) $newData[$object->id] = $object;`. You code then access the object using `$newData[$myID]`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's an array that contains StdClass objects , try looping over $myData and access each attribute :

```
foreach ( $myData as $data ) 
{
    print_r($data->id);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid loop by using following logic:

```
<?php 
$myID = 2;
$myData = json_decode(json_encode($myData),1); // Convert Object to Array

$id_arr = array_column($myData, 'id'); // Create an array with All Ids
$idx = array_search($myID, $id_arr);
if($idx !== false)
{
    echo $myData[$idx]['type'] . ' -- ' . $myData[$idx]['number'];
}
?>
```

*[Working Demo](https://eval.in/704945)*

> Note: `array_column` is supported from PHP 5.5.
>
> For lower versions you can use this beautiful library https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to achieve this, you need to pass the array and id whose details you want and the function will return the array with matching id, like below

```
function detailsById($myData,$id){
    foreach($myData as $data){
        if($data->id == $id){
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Just call this function with your array and id..

```
$data=detailsById($myData,2);
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
```

This will give you :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [busID] => 5
    [type] => APP
    [number] => 5125555555
)
```

And further to print 'number' and 'type' use `$data` array

```
$data['type'];
$data['number'];
```